# Using Flutter to develop a SDK to be used in Native iOS and Android

Tags: flutter

Our current app is written entirely on Flutter, and we need now to create an SDK to incorporate parts of it onto another native IOS and Android apps, liek we have in ZenDesk: https://developer.zendesk.com/embeddables/docs/android/welcome

My questions are:

- The SDK will have to display a full screen, make network calls and deal with isolates, I assume this can solve the problem: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Add-Flutter-to-existing-apps
- Is there a way to create a function that, without any view being displayed on the screen, starts an isolate and holds that data until the screen is shown for the first time?
- Is it possible to create Android Views with flutter to be included in an Android Activity? and the same for iOS

Answer (score 4):

I can answer these with regard to Android.

**Can I run Dart/Flutter code without a UI on Android?**

Yes, there is a new Android embedding in the works (still experimental as of May 2019), which allows you to execute a Dart entrypoint, e.g., `main()`, without ever attaching a `FlutterView`.

**Can I use a FlutterView instead of a FlutterActivity?**

Yes, with the new Android embedding you can integrate Flutter at the `View` level by using a `FlutterView`. There is also a `FlutterFragment`, which gives you most of the benefits of `FlutterView`, but also forwards a number of important calls that you would otherwise have to do yourself.

**Can I package my Flutter code as a library?**

Not yet. Currently, Flutter supports direct project linking from a Flutter project to an Android project. However, Flutter does not yet support the creation of an AAR that holds your Android and Flutter code. The Flutter team is working on this. Here is a ticket for tracking: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/26099

At the time of writing this, you can find docs on the new experimental API here:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Experimental:-Adding-Flutter-to-Android

Comment: First, again: thank you so much for replying! Does this mean that even compiling for a `jar` and/or uploading it to `bintray` to be added to an Android project is not yet possible?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by compiling to a jar. An Android library project can be built into an AAR. You may be able to get that working right now. But you might run into some difficulties. The Flutter team would like the process of building an AAR to be much easier.

Comment: Yes, sorry AAR, I have seen from the issues that in the following months it will be possible to bundle Flutter with the AAR (though there have been some who have solved this issue).  I'm very excited for that!

Comment: Great looks like `flutter build aar`  is now available on 1.8.3+. However any idea building a cocoa pod for iOS?

Answer (score 1):

More or less the same answers as [Matt's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56158188/167638) on iOS. You can invoke arbitrary dart entrypoint functions via https://api.flutter.dev/objcdoc/Classes/FlutterEngine.html#/c:objc(cs)FlutterEngine(im)runWithEntrypoint: whether it has UI or not.

You can also use platform channels to pass data back and forth before attaching any views to the FlutterEngine.

On both Android and iOS, you can embed Flutter views / view controllers into native activities / view controllers (though the Android API is still experimental at this stage).

This process will be more thoroughly documented on flutter.dev in the coming months.

Comment: For the third time: Thank you :D. Like I asked MattC, this means that I can or cannot create a library to be added in CocoaPods? Because (I might be naive) but it seems that it is possible, though it has some hurdles and experimental stuff at the moment